# Voice call from app to phone using sip and gateway

Tags: sip, voip, kamailio

How to implement voice calls to mobile/landline numbers from app(mobile client) using SIP server and gateway. how to configure the gateway with SIP?
i'm planning to use Kamailio since it's open source.

Comment: There is a lot of possible answers to your question, would you mind being a little more specific in your requirements?. It would be worth knowing if you want to use an external service as IP gateway or you would like to use an appliance and, in this case, what kind of telephone interfaces you have. Do you want to add voice (and video) features to your web app?, Do you prefer a dedicated application? (I do not suppose that, as StackOverflow is about software development)

Comment: I would suggest twillio.com. I am not affiliated with that company or anything like that but I see that as the most easy and fast way to deploy what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using an opensource turn-key solution based on Kamailio. E.g. Sipwise C5 https://www.sipwise.org/products/spce/features/

Just download it and install on a server or a VM.